# Word Add-in: Invalid signature in "on behalf of" flow

Tags: azure-active-directory, office-js, azure-ad-msal

I'm developing a Word Add-in and using auth.getAccessTokenAsync for authentication as defined here: https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync.

I obtain the access token successfully but then I'm encountering an error in the "on behalf of" flow described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/authorize-to-microsoft-graph.

While using MSAL (Microsoft.Identity.Client) to validate the bootstrap access token and get a token for Microsoft Graph I get an error. Code and error details below.

Code:

```
var cl = new ConfidentialClientApplication(<client ID>,
"https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + <tenant ID>,
<redirect uri>,
new Microsoft.Identity.Client.ClientCredential(<client secret>),
new Microsoft.Identity.Client.TokenCache(),
new Microsoft.Identity.Client.TokenCache());

var authResult = await cl.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOfAsync(new[] {
    "Sites.Read.All"
},
new Microsoft.Identity.Client.UserAssertion(accessToken));
```

Error:

```
AADSTS50013: Assertion contains an invalid signature. [Reason - The provided signature value did not match the expected signature value., Found key 'Start=02/18/2018, End=02/19/2020, Thumbprint=oZkMJ7Omv9GN7JVM', Configured keys: [Key0:Start=02/18/2018, End=02/19/2020, Thumbprint=oZkMJ7Omv9GN7JVM;Key1:Start=03/31/2018, End=03/31/2020, Thumbprint=xq4mEGikJ5Bkblfw;Key2:Start=11/16/2016, End=11/16/2018, Thumbprint=i1DVz66b9dfpPV3Z;]]\r\nTrace ID: 6ec996c8-517c-4baa-815b-54cee7913f00\r\nCorrelation ID: 4cc9d7dd-3879-4be4-a067-ed80eaaaad1d\r\nTimestamp: 2018-04-24 07:10:23Z
```

If I make a regular web app (not an Office add-in) and use MSAL.js to get an access token, that token validates fine.

As far as I can tell, there's a difference in the signature of the MSAL.js token versus the Word Add-in token. I'm using the same scopes, client ID and tenant ID.

Comment: According to the error, it should be caused by the different client credentails(the password/public key in the AADv2 ednpoint App). Check if they are matched.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how to verify this. There's a single password/public key in apps.dev.microsoft.com > Application Secrets, and a single application ID URI which is referenced in the Word Add-in manifest. If I use jwt.io to validate the MSAL.js access token signature and input the certificate, it validates fine. If I do the same thing with the Word Add-in token, the signature is invalid.

Comment: I think it may be the `<client  secret>` in your code.

Comment: It was a different issue entirely. I was using F12 Developer Tools from IE11 to get the access token. Currently it's not connected directly to an API, I just assign the access token to a global variable. I was using the console window to output that variable and was not aware that the dev tools truncate strings. Works fine now. :)

Comment: That makes scense! You're using same access token but the one for Word Add-in has been changed. Feel free to write an answer for this issue.:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to make sure that I'm getting the token correctly from the Word Add-in. IE11 F12 Developer Tools truncates strings when outputting a variable in the console window, so I just printed it on the UI instead and it works fine now.

Thanks Wayne Yang for helping me get to this point. :)